# push notifications not working on iOS with APNS and parse cloud functions (cloud functions working with android tho...)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-dashboard

I have been stuck on this for the past month now. All I have access to is parse dashboard version 1.4.24 which we are hosting on our own server on AWS. The push notifications were working over a year ago, but I think parse kinda ended and after that they haven't been working at all. I have tried updating apple push notification production and development certificates on the apple developer website but it doens't work. I think I need to add .pem files of the certificates on parse dashboard as well but I don't know where to add them. Please, someone help!!!!

I can't upgrade the parse dashboard either since that would mean to stop the server from running and we can't do that...

[what I see on the parse dashboard menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9zJB.png)

Comment: You actually need to upload your certificates to your parse server (not parse dashboard) and setup like this: http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#2-configure-parse-server

Comment: resolved! I had to go into the server code on aws and add certificate files in there through ssh-ing via the terminal. I appreciate your help tho!